# resource efficient join and filter method

Tags: r

I have the following condensed data set:

```
tbl1 <- data.frame(Name = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",2), rep("C",3)), Dat = c(1,1,2,1,1,3,4,4), 
                   Var1 = sample(1:8,8), Var2 = sample(1:8,8))

tbl2 <- data.frame(Name = c("A","A","B","C","C"), Dat = c(1,2,1,3,4), x = c("a","b","b","b","a"))
```

I need to filter from tbl1 all data sets with the condition x, found in table tbl2. This is my current solution.

```
tbl11 <- tbl1 %>% mutate(key = paste(Name, Dat, sep = "_"))
tbl2 <- tbl2 %>% mutate(key = paste(Name, Dat, sep = "_"))

tbl3 <- left_join(tbl11, tbl2)
tbl4 <- tbl3 %>% filter(x == "a")
```

Unfortunately I run into resource issues. For small tables it works. I think there are more efficient way so that I don't have to store the intermediate steps. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you just do `tbl3 <- left_join(tbl1, tbl2, by = c("Name", "Dat")) %>% filter(x == "a")` ? You could also filter both tables on `a` before joining.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the data before joining :

```
tbl4 <- merge(tbl1, subset(tbl2, x == 'a'), by = c('Name', 'Dat'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your ideas. Just for completeness, I have tested the suggested and came up with a correct and more efficient way:

```
tbl3 <- inner_join(filter(tbl2, x == 'a'), tbl1, by = c('Name', 'Dat'))
```

Inner_join is significantly faster than merge. And the order of the input is important of course.